# How can i send 2 parameters in multipart/form-data at restsharp?

Tags: c#, rest, restsharp

I'm using restsharp. trying to send 2 parametres, 1-yoksis_birim_id (int)

2-qualification: (string [json]). But when i try i get 1st parametre is empty response.
these are my codes;`enter code here`

```
string styleCreateUrl = "http://xxxx/service/qualificationcreate";
var client = new RestClient(styleCreateUrl);
 request.AddHeader("Postman-Token", "xxxx");
 request.AddHeader("cache-control", "no-cache");
 request.AddHeader("Content-Type", "application/json");
 request.AddParameter("Authorization", string.Format("Bearer " + token), ParameterType.HttpHeader);                    
 request.AddParameter("yoksis_birim_id", bolumid, ParameterType.RequestBody);
 request.AddParameter("qualification", bolum, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

and this is the sample of body in php:

```
   $request->setBody('------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="yoksis_birim_id"

xxxx
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4
Content-Disposition: form-data; name="qualification"

{"belge_type":"","thematic_code":[],"language":{"tr_TR":{"title":"","nonpreferredterms":"","description":"","further_info":"","further_source":"","url":"","eqflevel":"","nqflevel":"","informationlang":"","sourceofinformation":"","sup_lang":"","sup_url":"","nationaloccupation":"","relation":""},"en_US":{"title":"","nonpreferredterms":"","description":"","further_info":"","further_source":"","url":"","eqflevel":"","nqflevel":"","informationlang":"","sourceofinformation":"","sup_lang":"","sup_url":"","nationaloccupation":"","relation":""}}}
------WebKitFormBoundary7MA4Y');
```

Comment: Are you trying to pass two different parameters into the body of your request?

Comment: I edited my Q. Added php sample which i should make in c#. @WojtekT thank you for responding.

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you, you can pass multiple parameters to the request body by:

```
request.AddParameter("application/x-www-form-urlencoded", $"yoksis_birim_id={bolumid}&qualification={bolum}", ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

Comment: Still same response ; "You didn't send yoksis_birim_id".

Answer (score 0):

I send Parameters as JSON and pass in an object-class type for [data] to convert to string.

```
protected static IRestResponse SendRequest<T>(string baseUrl, string requestUrl, T data)
{
    var restClient = new RestClient(baseUrl);
    var request = new RestRequest(requestUrl, Method.POST);
    request.RequestFormat = DataFormat.Json;

    var json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.SerializeObject(data);
    request.AddParameter("application/json", json, ParameterType.RequestBody); // <-- Here
    var result = restClient.Execute(request);

    return result;
}

public static IRestResponse SendEmail()
{
    // Call The Function
    var result = SendRequest(baseUrl, urlPageToHit, emailReceiptDto);
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi. It still doesn't work. I added php sample, can you please check? @Demodave thank you for resonding.